# Read a dynamic value using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

Using Selenium I would like to the value of a element in a HTML. Like the following picture shows. The value "1841" is what I would like to extract. I can find the element for the next element by:

```
e = b.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'value_to_alert')]")
```

Now, the problem is I need to get the element before this element... Note that I cannot use the class name because there are a bunch of "KpiValue"s. Is there a way to do that?

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To retrieve the text **1841** from the previous `div` you can use the following line of code :

```
text = b.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(.,'value_to_alert')]//preceding::div[1]").text
```